# How to increase the memory size of tomcat-6

Tags: memory, tomcat6

I am using tomcat server as a windows service.which is responsible to open **tomcat6.exe** not **tomcat6w.exe**. I am facing the problem to increase the memory size for tomcat.does anyone know how to increase this size.I tried PR_JvmMx, PR_JvmMs etc but nothing is working. I am checking the size using http://localhost:8080/manager/status page 
in JVM section 
Free memory: 34.93 MB Total memory: 46.00 MB Max memory: 682.68 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running the tomcat as a windows service, it takes the arguments from windows registry [**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\\parameters**] . If you want to update the memory you need to update the registry directly or from tomcat5w.exe (**Open tomcat6w.exe goto Java tab and change the value of Initial memory pool & Maximum memory pool**) but for this purpose you must have the admin privilege. 
After modifying the size you must restart the tomcat service.
To check weather changes took affect or not you can use [Java melody Tool.](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/)
its very simple to install and having least overhead and will give you all of the information you wanted about server.

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/) will solve your problem

Comment: catalina.bat inside this folder will not be called while running the tomcat5.exe